# Maternity and child benefits for baby born outside Ireland

Tags: ireland, benefits

We are an Indian couple living in Ireland for more than 4 years and expecting our first baby on August’23. We are planning to have the baby's delivery in India and come back to Ireland after some time. Will I be entitled for maternity pay and child benefits pay? Also, can our baby get Irish citizenship after we both acquire it?

Comment: See https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/health/health_system/entitlement_to_public_health_services.html and https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/irish_citizenship/your_right_to_irish_citizenship.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer by @Andrey:

1. If your child is born in Ireland they **will** become Irish citizen at birth automatically, you just need to get the paperwork sorted (you will need to provide proof that you have been in the country legally and not as a student for at least 3 years before their birth)
2. If your child is born outside of Ireland they will **not** become an Irish citizen, and they will need their own visa to be able to come back with you to Ireland. Once there they will need to naturalize as a citizen at a later date once they become eligible (either on their own right, or after you naturalize yourself). There is a cost involved as well which is €200 as of writing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can receive child benefits when your child will be in Ireland.
2. If you born a child in Ireland and you are resident more than 3 years, your child can get the citizenship immediately. Otherwise they should be naturalised after you.